# Why doesn't Nest API Oauth Redirect?

Tags: nest-api

I've just begun playing around with the Nest API and am having trouble understanding why the OAuth2 server will not redirect a response to my redirecturi.

Example of my authentication attempt url:

```
https://home.nest.com/login/oauth2?client_id={ClientId}&redirect_uri=http://localhost&state=STATE
```

I'm able to authenticate and get a PIN back but ideally this is a response sent back to me and handled in my app dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind - I realized how can it possibly redirect to my localhost.  Oops!

Thanks for the comment David - I found the redirectURI on my clients page now...must have overlooked that before.

Comment: Right, `redirect_uri` is not supported, you must supply the redirect URI in the client page on developer.nest.com